# download manager doesn't catch url if I use onPageFinished method

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

Im using onpagefinished method to show url to the edittext this works.but not properly because it gives me problems with (if url ends with mp4 show download dialog) the dialog won't show,maybe onpagefinished isn't showing the current url?

I also tried `onLoadResource` and `onPagestarted` methods but still same problem

```
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,final String url) {
               if (url.endsWith(".mp4") { 
                                       //do smth }}}

wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                          super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                                          urlEdit.setText(view.getUrl());
                } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's not working because you are setting two different `WebViewClient`s.

You should declare your `WebViewClient` and then set it like this:

```
WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,final String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4") { 
            //do smth 
        }
    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        urlEdit.setText(view.getUrl());
    } 
};

wb.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
```